# Android black and white image processing

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

Hi I am developing a camera application in that I have to do black and white image processing.I goggled and found only gray scale image processing. I want to convert my image into black and white like cam scanner.Also I tried with openCv but the result is not up to our expectation.If anybody solved this means please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: Can you explain what black and white image processing means and why a grayscale is not a black and white image? Also post sample inputs your code and desired output

Comment: I am also using gray scale image processing plus i need black and white image processing too.If you have cam scanner means you can check that.

Comment: Then you're talking about thresholding the greyscale image such as sobel/laplacian or other kind of edge detection, at the moment your question is too broad as you've not shown what you've tried

Comment: I've already achieved edge detection .Bitmap bmpMonochrome_ = ((ScanActivity)getActivity()).getGrayBitmap(original); for gray scale and Bitmap bmpMonochrome_ = ((ScanActivity)getActivity()).getBWBitmap(original); for black and white using openCv.

Comment: Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmpMonochrome);
            ColorMatrix ma = new ColorMatrix(new float[]{
                    0.85f,0.85f,0.85f,0,
                    0,0.85f,0.85f,0.85f,
                    0,0,0.85f,0.85f,
                    0.85f,0,0,0,
                    0,0,2,0,
                    0,0,0,0,
                    0,2,0
            });

            Paint paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(ma));
            canvas.drawBitmap(original, 0, 0, paint); And I found this code while goggling.

Answer (score 0):

You will start with a grayvalue int[] or byte[] array with intensity values in the range [0, 255]. What you need is a threshold thres, so that all pixels with intensity  below that threshold are set to black (0) and all pixels with intensity equal or above that threshold are set to white (255). For tetermining the optimal threshold the [Otsu method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method) is a well established approach. It is rather intuitive. Since the threshold will divide the pixels into two subsets you take that threshold value that minimizes the variance within the two subsets - which is the same as maximizing the variance between the two subsets. As you see from the Wikipedia Link, the calculation is rather simple, they also provide the Java code. I work with this too and it is rather efficient.

Comment: I will try and comment my results. Thank you.